# Wordpress .htaccess Rewrite doesn't take effect

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have these rules in wordpress .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_speling.c>
CheckSpelling on
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (\.htm|\.html)
RewriteRule ^(.*)(\.htm|\.html)$ http://test.com/wordpress/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/wordpress/|/wordpress/images/)
RewriteRule ^(.*\.jpg)$ /wordpress/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I need to trigger this other rule that will apply a %20 replace only for file names, but it doesn't take effect:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule (.*)(\ |\%20)(.*)  /wordpress/$1-$2 [R=301,L]
```

Example of URL I need to test is:

```
http://test.com/some Folder/some Other subfolder/Some File Name.jpg
```

Needed Result:

```
http://test.com/wordpress/some Folder/some Other subfolder/some-file-name.jpg
```

Where I'm doing wrong? How can I accomplish with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule in your `DocumentRoot/.htaccess` for replacing white-spaces with hyphens:

```
RewriteRule ^(?:wordpress/)?(.*/)?([^\s\x20/]*)[\s\x20]+([^/]*)$ /wordpress/$1$2-$3 [R=302,L,NE]
```

Comment: It doesn't work.. I have tried with a Regex Positive Lookahead  which does the replacement (\ |\%20)(?=([^\/])*(\.htm|.\html|\.jpg)) the problem is that this works not at all if I put it in a WP plugin (Redirection) but not all the other redirects get triggered. Lowercase transformation doesn't happen. Replacement does'n trigger for html files only for jpg. I'm also unable to use that lookahead in a rewriterule to try it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104665/discussion-between-lizardhr-and-anubhava).

Comment: No, they are exactly how I have showed to you, I need to redirect from a non wordpress site to a wordpress one, with that rules..

Comment: In that case my given rule should be placed in DocumentRoot, i.e. a level above `wordpress` directory

Comment: what exactly x20 means in your rule?

Comment: It is `\x20` that matches `%20` in URL

Comment: All the rules work inside the wordpress folder not above but the %20 rules doesn't work neither in or above wp folder.

Comment: Hi @anubhava, just discovered that your updated rule, the second one, works fine without the: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f. The problem is that CheckSpelling on doesn't make lowercase transform any more. I have noticed that you have posted your solution with no RewiriteCond but I was using it like I have showed in full .htaccess. Any idea on how to make the lowercase transf working? (without %20 replace it works) thanks.

Comment: Lowercase conversion can be done only if you have control over `httpd.conf` file. You will need to add `RewriteMap lc int:tolower` line in order to have a rule here to lowercase the URL